# Prolog replace each instance of a constant in a list with a variable

Tags: prolog

Given list of constants, how can you replace each instance of a constant with a variable? Like  so:

```
[1,1,2,1,2,3]
```

=

```
[A,A,B,A,B,C]
```

This is my version:

```
f([],Seen0,Out,Out) :-
  write(Seen0).

f([H|T],Seen0,Out0,Out):-
  member(H/Var0,Seen0),
  append(Out0,[Var0],Out1),
  f(T,Seen0,Out1,Out).

f([H|T],Seen0,Out0,Out):-
  not(member(H/Var,Seen0)),
  append(Seen0,[H/Var],Seen1),
  append(Out0,[Var],Out1),
  f(T,Seen1,Out1,Out).
```

And runs like so:

```
?- f([1,1,2,1,2,3],[],[],O).
[1/_G31,2/_G58,3/_G118]
O = [_G31, _G31, _G58, _G31, _G58, _G118] .
```

And:

```
?- f([a,a,b,a,b,c],[],[],O).
[a/_G311,b/_G338,c/_G398]
O = [_G311, _G311, _G338, _G311, _G338, _G398]
```

Any other (better?) solutions?

Comment: Would it be useful if you could generate a list that looks like `[f(1,_), f(1,_), f(2,_), f(1,_), f(2,_), f(3,_)]` where each `_` is a distinct variable?

Comment: Not really. I want each unique constant to be represented by a unique variable.

Comment: The `f` list I showed *does* have a unique variable for each unique constant. I was just lazy and used the underscore to represent a variable because the name of the variable isn't known (you don't need to know it since you have `f`). I should have written it, `[f(1,_A), f(1,_A), f(2,_B), ...]`. What you show does seem to work, although I'd probably make `Seen` a fifth argument that comes back from the query rather than using `write` to display it. As far as whether there's a "better" solution, it's not possible to tell without knowing the usage context.

Comment: Were either of the answers given to you acceptable? If not, what remains at issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit simpler:

```
ints_vars([], [], _).
ints_vars([I|Is], [V|Vs], Map) :-
    once(member(I/V, Map)),
    ints_vars(Is, Vs, Map).
```

Giving:

```
?- ints_vars([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3], Vs, Map).
Vs = [_281, _281, _295, _281, _295, _315]
Map = [1 / _281, 2 / _295, 3 / _315|_321]
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

Comment: (+1) This also works with `memberchk(I/V, Map)` in place of `once(member(I/V, Map))`

Comment: @mbratch You can view Map as a potentially infinite, but lazily materialized map.

Comment: @mbratch If you want to close the map and prevent further entries, just call `append(Map,[],_)`, either in the base clause, or after success.

Answer (score 2):

```
to_vars(L, R) :-
    pairs_keys_values(Ps, L, _),
    maplist(peek(Ps), L, R).
peek(Ps, K, V) :- memberchk(K-V, Ps).
```

yields

```
?- to_vars([a,a,b,c,a],L).
L = [_G2400, _G2400, _G2418, _G2427, _G2400].
```

*edit* this one takes the idea from @jschimpf (+1) of using a free variable as 'dictionary'. Seems very clean to me...

```
to_vars(L, V) :- phrase(to_vars(_, V), L).

to_vars(_, []) --> [].
to_vars(Seen, [V|Vs]) --> [E], {memberchk(E-V, Seen)}, to_vars(Seen, Vs).
```